# Using VBA in Excel to run formulas - Formulas not working until reference cell activated

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Working in VBA, I've a simple worksheet function I am looking to paste down a certain number of rows.

```
Dim RowCount As Integer

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H2").End(xlDown).Row

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("L2" & RowCount).Value = "=IF(H2=""TRUE"",G2,"""")"
    .Range("M2" & RowCount).Value = "=IF(I2=""TRUE"",G2,"""")"
    .Range("N2" & RowCount).Value = "=IF(J2=""TRUE"",G2,"""")"
    .Range("O2" & RowCount).Value = "=IF(K2=""TRUE"",G2,"""")"
End With
```

My Calculation Options are set to automatic, so that is not the issue. I am also using "" for strings in the functions.

The code places the worksheet function where it should go, but the logic doesn't work. It always comes out false. But, when I click in the H2 cell being referenced by the function (I2, J2, K2), and then escape the cell, the text in H2 shifts left and the formula works! I don't want to do this for thousands of line items.  What should I do?

Comment: I cannot duplicate this behaviour.

Comment: What is the format type of the target "A2:L(n)" range?

Comment: Firstly, I tried a simple macro with only that code and it works, but secondly, I'm a bit confused... It seems you're putting this formula in cells `G2` and `H2` also... Can you put in more code, since I'm guessing the error has to do with something done elsewhere in the code....

Comment: I've added more code. I am not sure if the formula is coming out False or if the formula is not working. So for the first  statement to work, if I click in H2 and then click out, the formula populates correctly.

Comment: and bernie, the format type is GENERAL

Comment: Alright, so the data was dumped from Access and the reference cell was a checkbox or either TRUE or FALSE.  Therefore, the TRUE was not a string like the above formula suggests. The following formula works fine:  .Range("L2" & RowCount).Value = "=IF(H2=TRUE,G2,"""")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array formula instead of cell by cell formula. That way you enter the formula once for the whole range. See here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx for details. Do it by hand while recording a macro then adapt the code as needed.